# UIImage and UIimage.pngData returns two different image

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage, core-graphics

[image]

MRE

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    func maskImage(image: UIImage, mask: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let imageReference = image.cgImage!
        let maskReference = mask.cgImage!

        let width = maskReference.width
        let height = maskReference.height
        let bitsPerComponent = maskReference.bitsPerComponent
        let bitsPerPixel = maskReference.bitsPerPixel
        let bytesPerRow = maskReference.bytesPerRow

        let context = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
            bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue
        )

        context!.draw(maskReference, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

        let maskImage = context!.makeImage()!

        let maskedReference = imageReference.masking(maskImage)!

        return UIImage(cgImage: maskedReference)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: maskImage(image: UIImage(named: "uni")!, mask: UIImage(named: "mask")!))
                .background(.red)
            
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: maskImage(image: UIImage(named: "uni")!, mask: UIImage(named: "mask")!).pngData()!)!)
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

This code masks an image and returns a UIImage

You can see in the VStack that the first image is correct. It shows the masked image with a red background behind the masked area.

In the second image of the VStack, you can see that the transparency is gone.

So what I need to do is upload temp.pngData() to a server and expects to be able to view a png file with transparency preserved as shown in the preview code. But instead, when the file is uploaded I get the original without transparency.

How to fix?

Comment: `temp.pngData()` gives you a `Optional`, you must unwrap it before use in `UIImage(data: temp.pngData())`. Hint use `!` like you use **wrongly** everywhere in your code.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine it makes no different with !

Comment: I'm really surprised you can compile the code you show without using `!`, such as:
 `Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: temp.pngData()!)!)`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine you are right, I have made it less confusing by pasting the MRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make another image from the masked image if you need a merged one like a PNG:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: maskedImage.size)
let newImage = renderer.image { _ in maskedImage.draw(at: .zero) }
```

Now the masked area has been removed and you can use `newImage.pngData()` as expected

Comment: Also, note that you can merge **this logic** (not this code) into the `.turnedNotPureBlackIntoBlack()!` (from your other question) when you are coloring the new mask image.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of the code you show are invalid.

`maskImage()` isn't a valid call to your function. You're not passing in an image or a second image to mask it with. That shouldn't even compile.

Even if you invoke your `maskImage(image:mask:)` function with an image and a mask, it will return the image serialized in PNG format, which isn't the same thing as a `UIImage`.

Finally, you don't say what you are doing with your UIImage or the PNG data from your image, so we can't tell what you mean by "it won't work."

Comment: thank you I have updated the question with more info